# apache jmeter Test Script Recorder

Tags: java, apache, jmeter

While I am executing  Apache `JMeter HTTP(S)` Test Script Recorder as mentioned at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf . I am facing the error below when i press start button of `HTTP(s)` Test Script Recorder. Error is as below

Could not create script reording proxy - see log for details:

```
Command :"keytool -getkeypair -alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username:, C=US" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass{redacted)-keypass{redacted)-valididity 7 -ext bc:c' failed, code: 1
Illegal option: -ext
Try keytool -help
```

I tried upgrading the java version to 7, and `jmeter` version to 2.11 but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the following in environment variables:

- Create "JAVA_HOME", set its path to JRE directory

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0_40

- Set JAVA_HOME in **Path**

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Hope this will help.